# View [partials.header] not found. (View: W:\domains\iten\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I have front master.blade.php and home.blade.php

```
@include('partials.header')
@yield('content')
```

and route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

I get error

```
View [partials.header] not found. (View: W:\domains\iten\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php) (View: W:\domains\iten\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a `header.blade.php` in `views.partials` directory?

Comment: Can you show the path to `'partials.header'` relative to the root of your app?

Comment: Without seeing your directory structure we cannot help u for this question, post your directory structure here @Alisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename

```
header..blade.php
```

to

```
header.blade.php
```

There are two **dots** (..) in your view!

Answer (score 1):

I can see double dots in **header..blade.php** change it to **header.blade.php**.